# How to set keyboard layout when using sway?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, wayland

I am currently running **sway 1.4** on **Ubuntu 20.4.** I would like to permanently switch from `us` X11 Layout to `cz` layout `coder` variant.

I found some posts like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425424/keyboard-layout-with-sway-on-fedora-wayland#425433), where people describe how to do this on other distros. But when I tried some of the solutions they did not work for me. I think this might be distro-specific.

I also read [this manpage][2] and ran

```
sway input keyboard xkb_layout cz
```

which returned

```
[ { "success": true } ]
```

but the Czech layout has not been applied.

Comment: which man page do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
 input * {
        xkb_layout "cz"
        xkb_variant "coder"
}
```

to my sway config `~/.config/i3/config` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

`swaymsg input type:keyboard xkb_layout "cz"` in terminal worked for me